# SMD to DIP question

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, surface-mount

I bought one of these modules: https://www.decawave.com/product/dwm1000-module/

[image]

[image]

The problem is that its pins are very close together, they are not the same size as the traditional breadboard. I bought this adapter: https://es.aliexpress.com/item/1005001800916186.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2esp
[image]

But the problem is that it doesn't have spacer screw holes (I have to fix/mount it with screw).

I found this product on Amazon: [https://www.amazon.com/-/en/KeeYees-TQFP100-adaptor-plug-heads/dp/B085L8SK7Z/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B085L8SK7Z)
[image]

But I don't know if one of those will work for you. I'm new to electronics, so I don't know if SMD has a standard size or varies. Do you think it will work for you?

Comment: I don't see how any of those would work. "SMD" is a generic term for a *lot* of different layouts that are all surface mounted. There are standard packages, but I don't think that module follows any of them. I'm not sure why you need to mount it with a screw though? Once you solder the pin headers to both the adapter and the carrier boards, it should be very solid...

Comment: There are standard sizes. but I don't think 1.40mm between lands is one of them.

Comment: If you need full custom pcb you need to design it yourself ...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what you mean by "space screw holes". The adapter is designed to be used with the module you have, however you will not be able to use the 8 pin row in a solderless breadboard. They are the GPIO pins. You can solder downward-facing headers into the two six pin rows and an upward-facing row into 8 pin row. Similar to this Arduino board (photo from Banggood):

[image]

You could use jumper wires (female-male) if you need to access the GPIO pins.

The required headers are 2.54mm (0.1") pitch. There are various lengths available but common types which look more or less like those in the bottom of your photo will fit most solderless breadboards (rather tightly).

You'll also need to solder the castellated holes from the module to the adapter board.

If you need to "fix it with a screw" maybe you can use the SMA connector. Usually friction is enough for fiddling with stuff in a breadboard.

Answer (score 2):

solder the adaptor board to a strip-board or grid-board and then screw that board down.

Comment: That's my alternative, but it's not elegant. I prefer to use a single PCB as an adapter for my module, and use the hex spacer screws to mount it to my frame.

Comment: if you want a single PCB  you'll probably have to design one and order it.  several places will make small runs of PCBs (like 5 pieces) for a reasonable price (like $20+shipping)

Comment: much less than $20 if you can wait for shipping from China. Or go for oshpark.com in the US, which is also very cheap, or Aisler in Western Europe.